# Basic question regarding XSL template match

Tags: xslt, template-matching

I've just begun to tinker with XML, and I have a question.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<bucket version="Root Version 1A2B3C">
</bucket>
```

XSL FILE

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="bucket"> 
    <html>
       <body>
        <h3>
          <xsl:value-of select="@version"/>
        </h3>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have questions regarding the third line of the XSL. 
If I use

`<xsl:template match="bucket">` -  `Root Version 1A2B3C` is printed

`<xsl:template match="/">`   -

nothing is printed - I thought `"/"` means the root. 
My understanding is that it should either print "1.0" (`<?xml version`) or "Root Version 1A2B3C" (`bucket version)`

Please let me know why it is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: If you are curios then I would add another aspect. The `<?xml` part belongs to the so-called xml prologue. XML prologue may contain processing instructions, comments and doctype declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`/` denotes the document-node()  -- that is the whole document**.

In the provided XML the `bucket` element is the top element of the document. It isn't the root node.

**The top element `bucket` can still have siblings**, such as processing instructions or comment nodes. The top element together with its siblings all have a single parent and this is `/` -- the root node of the document.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node

> The root node is the root of the tree.
>   A root node does not occur except as
>   the root of the tree. The element node
>   for the document element is a child of
>   the root node. The root node also has
>   as children processing instruction and
>   comment nodes for processing
>   instructions and comments that occur
>   in the prolog and after the end of the
>   document element.

Always remember that (from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction):

> XPath operates on the abstract,
>   logical structure of an XML document,
>   rather than its surface syntax.

So, document root `/` means the "logical" root of the whole document.